# Why does the compiler compain not have field named "list"?

Tags: c++

I just write a code to have a randomaccessable list and the code is here.

```
MyList.h

#ifndef MYLIST_H
#define MYLIST_H

#include <list>
#include <initializer_list>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class MyList:public list<T>
{
private:
  T result;

public:
  MyList();
  MyList(initializer_list<T> li);
  T operator [](int i);
};

#endif // MYLIST_H
```

and the .cpp is here:

```
MyList.cpp

#include "mylist.h"

template<class T>
MyList<T>::MyList():list()
{

}

template<class T>
MyList<T>::MyList(initializer_list<T> li):list(li){

}

template<class T>
T MyList<T>::operator [](int i){
    auto temp = this->begin();
    for(int num=0;num!=i;++num){
        temp++;
    }
    return *temp;
}
```

But when I use it to have a test, something wrong with it. And the error information about it is here:
[image]

So why it would be wrong and how I can solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use inheritance, but composition, with standard containers.

Comment: That error is a red herring for the more fundamental mistake you made. Templated C++ classes cannot have their members defined in cpp files, you must define them in the header. Every `T` must compile into a different class... the cpp file cannot compile without knowing T, and the code where you use `MyList` (and provide `T`) has no implementations to use.

Comment: In addition to the other commenters' good advice. Also, I would suggest not creating an operator[] for something backed by a linked list. Appearing to have random-access capability on something that fundamentally does not is a great way to create performance issues.

Comment: @bhamlin that's not relevant; the same error appears if the definitions are moved into the header file

Comment: You really need to use `std::vector` not `std::list`

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify `list<T>` in mem-initializers of the constructors. For example

```
template<class T>
MyList<T>::MyList():list<T>()
{

}

template<class T>
MyList<T>::MyList(initializer_list<T> li):list<T>(li){

}
```

Though the first constructor could be written simpler

```
template<class T>
MyList<T>::MyList()
{

}
```

Or it could be defined in the class definition like

```
MyList() = default;
```

Answer (score 1):

You must define the constructor in the .h file:

```
MyList<T>::MyList() {};
```

and

```
MyList<T>::MyList(initializer_list<T> li):List<T>(Li) {};
```

Comment: That doesn't help with the intent to pass `li` as argument to `std::list` in the second case